# Why doesn't my animation loop?

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiview, uianimation

I need to perform a blinking effect on a image once the user click on a particular button. But my code doesn't work:

```
- (void)next
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
        NSLog(@"Done"); // <- USED AS COUNTER
        [image setAlpha:0];
        [image setAlpha:0.5];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

What happens is my `image` changing its alpha to 0.5 and stops. Furthermore my console shows `DONE` just one time. What did I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just created a test project and this blinked just fine...

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong)UIView *blinker;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.blinker = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    self.blinker.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.blinker];

    [self next];
}

- (void)next
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
        NSLog(@"Done"); // <- USED AS COUNTER
        [self.blinker setAlpha:0];
        [self.blinker setAlpha:0.5];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

With the exception that you expect the log to continue to print out in the console. So I suspect you are doing something to your image. You aren't calling self. so I am guessing it is an instance variable (ivar) and you are changing what it points to somewhere else in the code.

If you need a counter to go off every blink you may want to consider something like this...

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong)UIView *blinker;
@property (nonatomic,)NSInteger counter;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.blinker = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    self.blinker.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.blinker];

    [self next];
}

- (void)next
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        self.counter++;
        NSLog(@"Counter: %@", @(self.counter));
        self.blinker.alpha = 0.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            self.blinker.alpha = 1.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            //check to see if you want to continue blinking if so call next again
            [self next];
        }];
    }];
}
```

I don't have any context as to why you want to count, but hopefully that helps.